# Django - error message does not show on the form when submited

Tags: python, django

Hi I have an issue with the django form validation, here is the problem :

when I submit my form and the validation is not respecting the condition, the ValidationError() does not raise any message.

here is the code :

**views.py**

```
def AddArticle(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            save_it = form.save(commit=False)
            save_it.user = request.user
            save_it.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = ArticleForm()

context = {'form':form}
return render(request, 'template.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**template.html**

```
<form class="form" action="{% url "article.views.AddArticle" %}" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <div class="form-group fieldWrapper">
      {{ form.titre.errors }}
      {{ form.titre.label_tag }}
      {{ form.titre }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group fieldWrapper">
      {{ form.image.errors }}
      {{ form.image }}
   </div>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" />
</form>
```

**forms.py**

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article

    def clean_titre(self):
        titre = self.cleaned_data['titre']
        if len(titre) < 5:
            raise ValidationError('TITRE ERROR')
        return titre

form = ArticleForm()
```

What am I doing wrong ? Why does the error message doesn't display on the website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{ form.titre.error }}
```

The line above should be:

```
{{ form.titre.errors }}
```

It shown this way in [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)

Comment: The op updated their question 9 minutes ago with this change

Comment: I saw that and updated it, but this isn't the problem.

Comment: Could you supply the HTML output?

Comment: I found the problem, I reinstalled python again and everything seems to work fine, the issue came from my python system.